# Colorbox modal not resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, colorbox

I am using Colorbox to create my modals. Currently I have a modal that has a hidden div. When a `Show more`button is clicked, the hidden div will `fadeIn` and appear. However when the hidden div becomes visible, a scrollbar and part of this new div is not visible without scrolling down. In other words, the modal window did not resize to fit the new contents.

How can I make the modal window resize when the hidden div becomes visible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually by targeting the modal and changing the height to the height of the inner DIV.

```
var height = $('#innerDiv').height();
$('#modal').css('height',height);
```

Comment: is `#modal` the default id of the modal?

Comment: Using `$.colorbox.resize({innerWidth:560, innerHeight:750});` i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'resize' of undefined`

Comment: No, `#modal` is not the default ID, simply an example placeholder. As for your second comment: you'll need to look into the colorbox documentation for details about using colorbox methods.

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar problem, I tried following things:
first step try upgrading ColorBox to latest version, I am using v1.3.17.1 
In this js file add following customized resize function:

```
publicMethod.myResize = function (iW, iH) {
     if (!open) { return; }  
     if (settings.scrolling) { return; }  
     var speed = settings.transition === "none" ? 0 : settings.speed;  
     $window.unbind('resize.' + prefix);  
     settings.w = iW;  
     settings.h = iH;  
     $loaded.css({ width: settings.w, height: settings.h});  
     publicMethod.position(speed);  
    };
```

and give call to this function, I am giving call to this function as:

```
parent.$.fn.colorbox.myResize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
```

where var frameWidth & frameHeight are resp. width & height of the modal to which I want to resize the colorbox modal.  i.e. calculate the widht & height to which you want to resize the modal and pass these values to this customized resize function. Probably you should try calling this function after some time period (e.g. using settimeout()), this will help to calculate the width & height to set, hope this helps...!!!